# Why are these Rasters out of alignment and how can it be corrected in QGIS?

Tags: raster, alignment

**Background**

A series of raster files have been created over the same area of land over the last 2 years using a DJI Phantom 4 Multispectral Drone connected to a DJI RTK (https://www.dji.com/au/phantom-4-rtk) and using DJI Terra software to stitch the photos to form a complete raster image.

DJI default is CRS EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 and this is what is set for the QGIS Project to avoid any reprojection issues. GSD is 5cm.

Using the above equipment and process, raster files should have centimeter level accuracy. The RTK kit can be used for civil survey projects and should be more than accurate for this projects purpose.

What I would expect is for each raster to accurately align up so each corresponding tree is also aligned through the raster file layers, however this is not the case. Each raster is out slightly by about 0.5m to 1.95m meters.

Taking 4 Rasters as example, and placing a point at the tree crown center (manually) for each raster image illustrates the issue.

**Illustration 1**

Image 0327-Blue on the left showing blue points at each tree crown across the farm. Red circle indicating the zoomed in area for the same image in the Right
[image: Illustration 1]

**Illustration 2**

**The left image**

Process repeated for each corresponding raster

- Raster 0928 is Red Points
- Raster 0711 is Yellow points
- Raster 01125 is Pink Points

The under lying raster image is 0327 – Blue for consistency

**The Right Image -**

A comparison of the same area is **Raster 01125 – Pink** with the corresponding pink points on the center of the tree crowns. Note the position of the PINK point on the left image. It is offset to the left of the tree indicated by the arrow, but is in the center of the tree crown in the right image.

[image: Illustration 2]

**Illustration 3**

Using Illustration 2 left image Yellow arrow points to the tree that is zoomed in below. Showing the distance variations between the same tree for the different raster points.

- Distance from Blue point to Pink point is 1.91m
- Distance from Blue point to Red point is 1.0m
- Distance from Blue point to yellow point is 0.5m

[image: Tree ofsets]

Here are the Properties of 2 rasters.

- the Blue points

[image: Raster for Blue Points]

- and the Red Points

[image: Raster for Red Points]

I think what needs to happens is each raster need to be “moved” to align to an agreed point e.g Blue but I am not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to move some of your images to align with other images you can look up how to do georeferencing in QGIS.  There are many examples available on the internet.

Why is it happening?  Good question.  Assuming your RTK GNSS unit is set up correctly then the image  X, Y values should be highly accurate for the location of the drone at image capture time.  This accuracy will translate into better reconstruction accuracy  if and only if the RTK values are being written to the image EXIF data.  I cannot say for your P4P-RTK drone but not too long ago many DJI drones with RTK units were only using RTK for navigation and the consumer grade GNSS was doing the image geotagging.

Confirm that the RTK values are making their way into the EXIF data.  Also, the alignment of the images in structure from motion software relies on the pitch, roll, and yaw of the camera at image capture time.  The IMU unit in this camera may not provide the precision or accuracy to allow for the accuracy you desire.

Comment: thank you @GBG.  I have scoured YouTube and training docs last week on realigning raster using GRASS, SAGA or the QGIS Georeferencer tool and using Align Raster tool. All with not much success. They all seem to want to change pixels, warp the image using a number of different resampling methods. Unless i am missing something i just want to select one raster by a tree and overlay it to the same tree in another raster layer. Is the origin, extent or pixel size the problem? Although # of pixels between 2 points on each raster is the same.
Other issue - DJI support is assisting -answer TBA

Comment: A first order polynomial transformation during georeferencing will only shift, scale, or rotate your image.  The values of the pixels will not change.

Comment: Again Thank you @GBG.  I am getting there! I undertook georeferencing using your suggestion and following this [Link](https://gis-university.com/georeferencing-in-qgis/). 
BUT SCALE is massive now on the modified tiff. After researching further, I created a new QGIS project, set Project CRS to EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 as well as ensure all tiffs were the same CRS as too the Transform CRS. GCP were done using canvas inputs. I used 4 points one on each CNR tree. Same result modified file is massive. Measuring tool confirms original raster is to scale. Any suggestions?

Comment: Residual Pixels values are between 2.6 and 6.0

Comment: Comments are not meant to have running discussions on GIS SE.  Best to accept the answer as answered and post a new question about the specifics of reducing the residual values in a georeferencing task in QGIS.

Comment: No Problem - Good to know thanks. 
Link to new question [https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/456039/167567]